Fans keep spinning up after BIOS update despite no activity
I'm in the process of updating my CPU from an 1800X to a 3700x, and in order to be able to do so, I've needed to update my BIOS in a multi-step process, as follows:

Updates BIOS to P3.50

Installed AMD all in 1 with VGA driver ver:18.10.20_NHDA

Updated BIOS to P5.10

Installed AMD all in 1 with VGA driver ver:18.50.16.01_WHQL

Updated BIOS to P5.40


->
(6. Hopefully be able to replace 1800X with 3700X)
(7. Update BIOS further if needed)
Everything went swimmingly until I had updated BIOS to P5.40, after which the fans started spinning up like crazy despite no processes using up any major resources. The fans spin up, then starts spinning up to the max and staying there for a minute, then slows down (but never settles down to normal), then spins up to the max again, the slows down, etc, in intervals. The CPU stays at a constant 30C/86F (checked with F-stream Tuning/A Tuning), and the system is working normally in all other respects.
Any ideas what's going on, and what I can do to fix it?
System:
Windows 10, OS and all drivers up to date
ASRock X370 Killer SLI
Ryzen 7 1800X (using the stock Wraith Prism cooler that came with my new 3700X)
Corsair CX750 PSU
64 GB RAM (only 48GB is being addressed after I reseated the sticks, despite shuffling them around several times, cleaning the slots and the sticks carefully - never had a problem with them before)

If you open the UEFI, can you check the fan settings? I'd recommend changing them even if they don't appear to need changing, and observing anything that may have change.

"Any ideas what's going on, and what I can do to fix it?" - System is bricked.  Does the motherboard have failover firmware?

Thanks music2myear. I'll check the UEFI settings if anything looks weird - but it's odd that a BIOS update would randomly change my fan settings, isn't it? Especially considering that the previous BIOS updates didn't cause this.

Ramhound - the system boots up and works just fine, everything is normal except the weird fan behavior.
